# remove returns in excel read in

Tags: r, excel, regex, dataframe

I am reading a couple excel files in and merging them into one dataframe. Some of the address fields have returns in them. I came up with this to remove them but it does not work and RStudio says that there are invalid tokens in the line.

```
df$Primary.Street <- gsub("\r\n", " ", df$Primary.Street)
```

Any help would be much appreacited.

Sample of input row of how it looks in Excel:

```
            "123 Main St
"Sam Jones"  Apt A"      "New York" "NY" "12345"
```

Desired output to csv:

```
"Sam Jones","123 Main St Apt A","New York","NY","12345"
```

Comment: Can you please share how it looks in R? `dput(df[row_that_has_problem, relevant_columns])` would be perfect, as it will include all class and structure information.

Comment: First, make sure the line breaks are really part of the `df$Primary.Street`, then use `df$Primary.Street <- gsub("(*UCP)\\R+", " ", df$Primary.Street, perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your carriage return characters in square brackets to create a character class, which will match any character in the class:

```
> samp <- "120 Main st\nApt A"

> gsub("[\r\n]+", " ", samp)

[1] "120 Main st Apt A"
```

Your example without the brackets would only match a `\r` and `\n` in sequence. My example here will match any sequence of one or more of either (via the `+` quantifier).

Comment: I'm going to try that tomorrow. I'm going to wrap it in an `ifelse` for the rows that do not have the `\r\n`.

Comment: Rows that don't have it will not change, `ifelse` is not strictly necessary.

Comment: I was overthinking at the moment. I was looking up more than one function when I posted this question.